# The mean of a variable keeps coming back as NA

Tags: r, mean

```
Hrstart <- c(MNC$hrstart)
Hrstart
mean(Hrstart) 
[1] NA
```

I wanted to get the mean of a variable (hrstart) but it keeps returning as NA.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Most likely some elements of it are non-numeric.  Can you give some example data to work with?

Comment: You are right. I used 'na.rm = TRUE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be `NA` in your data. To get rid of them, use `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
mean(Hrstart, na.rm = TRUE)
```